# Changing color scheme of Facebook commenting box when dark mode is on

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, facebook

I am running a small wordpress website, and recently I have implemented a dark mode feature.
I was able to correct everything that wasn't changing properly in custom css by using:

```
body.wp-night-mode-on .element_class {
   background-color: #...;
   color: #...;
}
```

But was very unsuccessful when trying to do the same thing with Facebook plugin (using "Lazy Social Comments" plugin for that).

I have tried addressing .comments-area .fb-comments and **literally** every thing I have found in source code. I know I can change the theme from "data-colorscheme="light"" to dark in settings, but the idea is to do it dynamically.

Really hope that somebody knows the answer because I have been on it for 3 days already.

Thank all of you in advance!!

P.S - I am a very new to this :)

[Dark Mode Off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcJYr.png)
[Dark Mode On](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRt93.png)

Comment: Cant you right-click the element and check what attributes are present? This should probably do the trick to find the right attribute you have to change.

Comment: Hi, maybe I am missing something, but I have tried applying it to every single class I have found when inspecting the element :(

Comment: You need to change the corresponding attribute on the HTML element that is used to embed the plugin, and then call the method `FB.XFBML.parse()` to get it re-parsed and rendered with the new setting. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll do some research (as I said I am new to this) and give it a shot!